# How to render an element on top of every other element on page without depending on the structure/styles used in the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to display a button at a fixed position(sticky) on the page and it should always be on top of other elements on the page, assuming I have no knowledge of the structure and styles used on that page. The solution can only use Javascript(no jQuery), CSS3 and HTML5.

**The solution has to be dynamic/adaptive i.e not directly dependent on the z-index values used on the page.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/sf1fukm5/

CSS:

```
.a {
    position:fixed;
    right:10px;   //optional
    top:10px;    //optional
    z-index:1;
    background:grey; //optional
    color:#000;   //optional
    padding:20px;  //optional
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>--Content--</div>
<div class="a">Fixed</div> //Fixed div
<div>--Content--</div>....
```

For dynamic z-index using jQuery:

```
var highest = -999;
$("*").each(function () {
    var current = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"), 10);
    if (current && highest < current) highest = current;
});
$('your-element-selector').css('z-index',highest);
```

Using javascript:
[How can you figure out the highest z-index in your document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118198/how-can-you-figure-out-the-highest-z-index-in-your-document)

Refer: [How to find the highest z-index within a document no matter what tags they are?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686544/how-to-find-the-highest-z-index-within-a-document-no-matter-what-tags-they-are)

Comment: I think this won't work if there is another fixed element with z-index greater than 1. An example of such a scenario would be bootstrap's fixed nav-bars

Comment: You can always change the z-index. I used 1 just for demo purpose. You can set it higher than the maximum z-index in the page. It all depends on your design

Comment: I am looking for a dynamic solution. It should not directly depend on the styles used on the page. It should adapt.

Comment: @Kasahs Set z-index :2147483647 . This is the highest value of z-index. Else, write a jquery code which finds the element with highest z-index, increment it by one and add it to concerned element's css.

Comment: I am working on the second option(though i can't use jquery) i was wondering if there was a better solution. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: For future readers:
I am marking this as the correct answer despite the use of jquery as the link @K K shared contained the required javascript solution(I came up with my own so did not use it but it essentially does what i did so should work.) Thanks K K.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0f507Lq0/)

CSS:

```
.fixed-button {   
      width: 125px; 
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 999;
      top: 70px;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button class="fixed-button"> fixed-button </button>
```

I hope you got the answer. You can change the position of button where ever you need

Comment: What if there is a fixed element with z-index greater than 999(example scenario will be bootstrap's fixed nav-bar)? I am looking for a dynamic solution.